# Вопрос по css и jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

У меня есть работающий код jquery. У меня вопрос: какое свойство здесь показывает в какую сторону будет показываться блок и как можно поменять сторону появления блока? Большое спасибо

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script> 

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#flip").click(function(){
$("#panel").toggle(900);
});

}

});

</script>
<style>

#panel, #flip {
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #e5eecc;
border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel {
padding: 50px;
display: none;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Возможности указать методу `.toggle()`, с какой стороны должен показываться элемент, к сожалению нет. Мы можем указать только лишь время анимации появления/скрытия элемента.

```js
$('#flip').on('click', function() {
  $('#panel').toggle(900);
});
```

```css
#panel,
#flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel {
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

Вероятнее всего, вам нужна анимация появления элемента сверху вниз, как шторки. В таком случае, используйте метод `.slideToggle()`.

```js
$('#flip').on('click', function() {
  $('#panel').slideToggle(900);
});
```

```css
#panel,
#flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel {
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

Любую другую анимацию мы можем использовать в случае добавления/удаления дополнительного класса к элементу, который показываем. И это будет уже анимация CSS. Вот простой пример такой анимации:

```js
$('#flip').on('click', function() {
  $('#panel').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
#panel,
#flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.active {
  background-color: #e5eecc !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

И еще пример:

```js
$('#flip').on('click', function() {
  $('#panel').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
#panel,
#flip {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 38px;
  left: calc(50% - 8px);
  width: 0;
  padding: 50px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.active {
  left: 8px !important;
  width: calc(100% - 16px) !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
```